# How to keep searching through my array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm making a version of "Rush Hour" which is a game where you're suppose to move cars around in order to allow a specific car to move through. For my program, if the user enters... let's say GR1 (G standing for which car to move, R standing for direction(right), and 1 for how many spaces to move in that direction) Then the car is suppose to 1 space to the right. I've noticed that for my program, it'll only move one part of the car. What I think is happening is that my loop doesn't go through my whole array. Once it finds the first part of the car, it'll move it and then just go right back through the loop. How can I move the whole car?

Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
--------
|GG...Y|
|P..B.Y|
|PRRB.Y>
|P..B..|
|O...TT|
|O.FFF.|
--------
```

// entering GR1 should give me

```
--------
|.GG..Y|
|P..B.Y|
|PRRB.Y>
|P..B..|
|O...TT|
|O.FFF.|
--------
```

// but gives me this instead

```
--------
|G.G..Y|
|P..B.Y|
|PRRB.Y>
|P..B..|
|O...TT|
|O.FFF.|
--------
```

//code a and c are user inputs

```
 for(i=64; i>0; i--)
    {
            if(board[i] == a)// if user input is found checks board
            {
                a = i;
                tmp = board[a];
                board[a] = board[a+c];
        //printf("The value of the swapping position is %c\n", board[a+c]);
        if(board[a+c]!= '.' || board[a+c]=='|')
            {
            printf("Invalid move. exiting..\n");
            return 0;
            }
                board[a+c] = tmp;
                printf("the value of a is %c\n", a);
            }
}
```

Comment: What is a and c here. From your example, I assume a = 'G' and c = '1'. Where is the input variable for 'R' in 'GR1'.

Comment: b = 'R' is suppose to mean "right" but before I took user input for which turn to move the car in, I wanted to make sure that I could get the cars to move together first. So, I didn't put in the code yet for variable b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have given in input G is in position board[0] and board[1] right?. but when you loop through board you are not going till board[0] since the condition being checked is i>0.therefore the G in board[0] position is not moving. so make this change.

```
for(i=64; i>0; i--)
```

change the for to

```
for(i=64; i>=0; i--)
```

remember that array indexing is done from 0 to size-1. so check even about 64. whether it is array_size-1.
the error is cause of statement a=i

```
if(board[i] == a)// if user input is found checks board
    {
        a = i;
```

that is executed when first matching G is obtained. since a=i changes a's value the rest of the G's are not detected beacuse a != 'G' anymore it is a=i after getting first matching G.

use some other variable and avoid changing value of a by a=i. or restore the value of a='G' before the next iteration starts after getting the matching 'G'.

Comment: Actually it wouldn't matter if I searched through the array til position [0]. So, I might've been pretty vague, but if 'G' is in position [10] and also in [12] then it wouldn't matter because my program will only deal with the [12] at the moment. I'm trying to get my code to be able to move both the position at [10] and [12] after inputting one command from user input

Comment: @user3370224 ok. got the error is cause of statement a=i that is executed when first matching G is obtained. since a=i changes a's value the rest of the G's are not detected beacuse a != 'G' anymore it is a=i after getting first matching G.